# Меняя чекбокс, менять значение поля в объекте. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Есть таблица, строки которой динамически формируются из массива. Большинство колонок - это характеристики "да/нет". В каждой характеристике в массиве стоит значение selected. При выводе верстки значение чекбокса checked зависит от selected. Вывод происходит без проблем. Но я не могу сообразить, как сделать обратную зависимость, чтобы при смене состояния чекбокса соответствующее значение заносилось в объект. Вроде элементарная задача, а найти решения не могу уже несколько часов. Вот общая картина верстки этой таблицы:

```
<table class="newnew" [attr.data-vehicles]="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th *ngFor="let item of arrayObjects">{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of arrayObjects; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
         <td *ngFor="let item of routeVehicle.vehicleQualities">
            <input [attr.data-uuid]="item.uuid" type="checkbox" [checked]="item.selected" (change)="changeCheckbox($event)">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз:

```
public changeCheckbox(item: Item): void {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
}
```

Также в шаблоне нужно передавать аргументом не событие, а сам объект `item`:

```
(change)="changeCheckbox(item)"
```

Два:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.selected" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }">
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почти сработало. Только значение меняется не с первого раза. Первый клик снимает галочку с чекбокса, но в объекте значение остается true. Второй клик меняет значение на false. Обратный процесс тот же самый: первый клик возвращает галочку, второй - меняет значение на true. Почему так?

Comment: Разобрался. Заменил (change) на (click) и заработало, как надо. Еще раз спасибо тебе.

Comment: А ты можешь подсказать, как правильно продублировать этот объект? Сейчас я создаю новый объект, присваиваю его полям поля из текущего объекта (я думал, так значения можно передать), потом пушу этот объект в массив. А получается, что меняя чекбокс в новой строке, меняется чекбокс и в старой. Получается, что при копировании передалось не значение параметра, а ссылка на этот параметр. Как продублировать объект, чтобы его параметры были самостоятельными, но при этом на момент дублирования были такие же, как у копируемого объекта?

Comment: Не совсем понял твой вопрос :( лучше на stackblitz создай пример